# Need help to scrape video streaming url from websites for android app

Tags: java, android, jsoup, screen-scraping

Hi I need to scrape video streaming  urls from website

```
   https://afdah.to 
   https://flixanity.xyz 
   http://streamm4u.com
```

I am using jsoup to extract the website content .However I have no idea how can I get the video streaming link from these websites.I tried reading their source code but couldn't find something.

Comment: Any answer we give you could break tomorrow.  That's why using tools like JSOUP are really  to be avoided.  If a site doesn't have an API to give you that info, you should find one that does.

Comment: I am not looking for a permanent solution it's just for temporary work .